# How to use an htm file converted from word in my react js

Tags: reactjs, vite

I want to use my converted word to htm in my react app

Here is my AdminLayout

```
import { React, Fragment } from 'react'
import { useStateContext } from '../../context/ContextProvider'
import { NavLink, Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Bars3Icon, BellIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import axiosClient from '../axios/axios';

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '#', current: false },
  { name: 'Manage Users', to: '/admin/manageusers'},
  { name: 'Forms', to: '/admin/forms'},
  { name: 'Submited Forms', to: '/admin/submitedforms'},
  { name: 'Employee Activity Form', to: '/admin/EmployeesActivityForm.htm'}
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function AdminLayout() {
    const { userToken } = useStateContext();

    const logout = (ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      axiosClient.post('/logout')
        .then(res => {
          setCurrentUser({})
          setUserToken(null)
        })
    };

    if(!userToken){
        return <Navigate to='/' />
    }

    return (
      <>
        {/*NavBar*/}
        <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-gray-800">
          {({ open }) => (
            <>
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

                <div className="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">

                  <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                    {/* Mobile menu button*/}
                    <Disclosure.Button className="relative inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
                      <span className="absolute -inset-0.5" />
                      <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                      {open ? (
                        <XMarkIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                      ) : (
                        <Bars3Icon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                      )}
                    </Disclosure.Button>
                  </div>

                  <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">

                    <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center">
                      <img
                        className="h-8 w-auto"
                        src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
                        alt="Your Company"
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block">
                      <div className="flex space-x-4">
                        {navigation.map((item) => (
                          <NavLink
                            key={item.name}
                            to={item.to}
                            className={({ isActive }) => classNames(
                              isActive ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' 
                                       : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                              'block rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-base font-medium'
                            )}
                          >
                            {item.name}
                          </NavLink>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="relative rounded-full bg-gray-800 p-1 text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800"
                    >
                      <span className="absolute -inset-1.5" />
                      <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                      <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                    </button>

                    {/* Profile dropdown */}
                    <Menu as="div" className="relative ml-3">
                      <div>
                        <Menu.Button className="relative flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800">
                          <span className="absolute -inset-1.5" />
                          <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                          <img
                            className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </Menu.Button>
                      </div>

                      <Transition
                        as={Fragment}
                        enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                        enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                        enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                        leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                      >
                        <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                          <Menu.Item>
                            {({ active }) => (
                              <a
                                href="#"
                                className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                              >
                                Your Profile
                              </a>
                            )}
                          </Menu.Item>

                          <Menu.Item>
                            {({ active }) => (
                              <a
                                href="#"
                                className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                              >
                                Settings
                              </a>
                            )}
                          </Menu.Item>

                          <Menu.Item>
                            {({ active }) => (
                              <a
                                href="#"
                                onClick={(ev) => logout(ev)}
                                className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                              >
                                Sign out
                              </a>
                            )}
                          </Menu.Item>

                        </Menu.Items>

                      </Transition>

                    </Menu>

                  </div>

                </div>
                
              </div>

              <Disclosure.Panel className="sm:hidden">
                <div className="space-y-1 px-2 pb-3 pt-2">
                  {navigation.map((item) => (
                    <NavLink
                      key={item.name}
                      to={item.to}
                      className={({ isActive }) => classNames(
                        isActive
                          ? 'bg-[#CCEFCC] text-[#737373]'
                          : 'text-[#737373] hover:bg-[#CCEFCC] hover:text-[#737373]',
                        'rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium'
                      )}  
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </NavLink>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Disclosure.Panel>
            </>
          )}
        </Disclosure>

        <main>
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my Router

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import GuestLayout from "./views/unauthorizedView/main_views/GuestLayout";
import AdminLayout from "./views/authorizedView/AdminLayout";
import ManageUsers from "./views/authorizedView/admin/ManageUsers";
import Forms from "./views/authorizedView/Forms/Forms";
import SubmitedForms from "./views/authorizedView/Forms/submitedForms/SubmitedForms";
import EmployeeActivityForm from "./views/printableForms/employeeActivityDesign/EmployeeActivityForm";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <GuestLayout />
    },

    {
        path: '/admin',
        element: <AdminLayout />,
        children:[
            {
                path: 'manageusers',
                element: <ManageUsers />
            },
            {
                path: 'forms',
                element: <Forms />
            },
            {
                path: 'submitedforms',
                element: <SubmitedForms />
            },
            {
                path: 'EmployeesActivityForm.htm',
                element: <EmployeeActivityForm />
            }
        ]
    },
])

export default router;
```

here is my EmployeeActivityForm that contains the path to my htm file

```
import React from 'react';

class EmployeeActivityForm extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
         <iframe src="./EmployeesActivityForm.htm"></iframe>
      );
   }
}

export default EmployeeActivityForm;
```

I converted my word file into htm an i want to render is as a part of my react app. but the out put is it only retenders the app [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEkIQ.png).

[Here is the folders/files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgtt1.png)